# Merge 3 Arrays 2D arrays Dimension Wise to make a 6D array

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

so I have three Arrays of dimension  (1949, 2649)

```
Jun_1TMean = xr.DataArray(Jun_1T.variables['__xarray_dataarray_variable__'])
lon = xr.DataArray(lon2)
lat = xr.DataArray(lat2)
```

When I do

```
June_1T =np.array( [Jun_1TMean, lat, lon])
June_1T.shape
```

I get  (3, 1949, 2649)

However I actually  want shape (1949, 2649, 1949, 2649, 1949, 2649) instead

Comment: Where would the data for the extra dimensions come from, how would they be filled? And how much space (=RAM) do you expect to need for storing that data explicitely?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa doesnt matter how much ram he has, even the whole of internet is not that much

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I had hoped Connor to come to realize that.

Comment: Yeah, rip. I want to keep lat lon data together with the variable of interest. I am trying to separate east --> west coast. Then average day and night. I want to keep lat lon with the data while separateing / concating timezones so when I plot the data is assigned the proper coordinate. Since each time zone has a different  UTC day/ night

Comment: I doubt that you need the amount of dimensions you think you do.

Comment: No I don't probably np.where or some other function to associate two data sets together with some sort of filter

Comment: While [edit]s to the question to provide clarification and/or additional information are encouraged, edits which change the question sufficiently to invalidate an already posted answer are not permitted. In fact, the consensus is that any user with [edit privileges](/help/privileges/edit) should revert such edits. I have done so here. Please note that this doesn't prevent you from completely changing a question prior to any answers being posted. If you desire, you're welcome to post a [new question](/questions/ask) on your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact you cant just 'stack' NumPy arrays as separate axes, without a broadcastable function or `ufunc` like `+`, `*`, etc, I don't think you want to be doing that. A numpy array with those dimensions as you suggest, which has a dtype `int64` (float will be worse) will take -

```
array_space = (1949*2649*1949*2649*1949*2649)*8 bytes 
            = 1100959591182509749608 bytes
            = 1100959591182.51 GB
            = 1100959.59 Petabytes
```

For reference, the combined data of Google, Amazon, Microsoft and Facebook collectively is [estimated](https://starry.com/blog/inside-the-internet/how-big-is-the-internet#:%7E:text=Science%20Focus%20estimates%20that%20Google,petabytes%20is%201.2%20million%20terabytes.) to be 1,200 petabytes